# vhdl generate multiple range

Tags: vhdl

I have 2 checks which are similar, except by the range of the generate:
All works OK, it looks like this:

```
check : for bit in (1 to 5)  generate  
  process
          some cool stuff;
  end process;
end generate  check ;

check2 : for bit in (7 to 8)  generate  
  process
          Same some cool stuff;
  end process;
end generate  check2 ;
```

I would like to implement something simpler to maintain like this:

```
check : for bit in (1 to 5) & (7 to 8)  generate  
  process
          Simpler to mantain the cool stuff;
  end process;
end generate  check ;
```

Is this possible ??

Comment: In this case you could do a range of `1 to 8` and add an `if not 6`

Comment: No. A for generate parameter specification is a single discrete range. A range consists of scalar bounds and a direction.

Comment: Question apart, 'BIT' is datatype keyword ... So it can't be used as indexing for generate I guess.

Comment: The 'bit' parent byte/word etc must be named first. Bit cans must be named.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your range as an array and use the for-loop to run through this array:

```
type arr is array(0 to 7) of integer;
constant bit : arr := (0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8);

[..]
check : for i in 0 to 7 generate
   cool_stuff(bit(i));
end generate;
```

Answer (score 0):

i followed the "oldfart" user sugestion , and did a range 1 to 8 and added an if not for 6...

There probably cleaner ways to do it , but it works..

i'm still interested in cleaner ways...